# Make patches bigger used as legend inside matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am adding patches in a plot inside `matplotlib` using `from matplotlib.patches import Patch` class. Please see the sample code below-

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

n = 5
hatch_1 = 'o'
hatch_2 = '.'
opacity = 0.4
bar_width = 0.4

y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=n)
x = np.arange(n)

bars = plt.bar(x, y, bar_width, align='center',  alpha=opacity, fill=False)
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_hatch(hatch_1)

y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=n)
bars = plt.bar(x + bar_width, y, bar_width,
               align='center',  alpha=opacity, fill=False)
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_hatch(hatch_2)

patch_1 = Patch(fill=False, label='Hatch 1', hatch=hatch_1, alpha=opacity)
patch_2 = Patch(fill=False, label='Hatch 2', hatch=hatch_2, alpha=opacity)

# add legends
plt.legend(handles=[patch_1, patch_2], loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

Below is the generated plot-
[image: screenshot of the plot]

The hatches used for legends aren't visisble properly. I guess if I make the patches bigger, it will be visible.

**How to make patches bigger?**

Comment: I don't know if there is an easy way to change the size of the hatch pattern (that is, without creating a new hatch from scratch). In the mean time, you could increase the hatch density in the legend: `patch_1 = Patch(fill=False, label='Hatch 1', hatch=2*hatch_1, alpha=opacity)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the size of the legend patches in a couple of ways.

First, you can increase the width using the `handlelength` option to `plt.legend`.

However, there is no way to increase their height using kwargs. So we need to loop over the patches after creating the legend. If we keep a reference to the legend as we create it `leg = plt.legend(...)`, then we can loop over the patches using `for patch in leg.get_patches():`.

Then you can change the height of the patch using `patch.set_height()`.

However, all this tinkering means they won't be aligned quite right. So we also need to change their vertical position slightly (using `patch.set_y()`).

I also found it helped to increase the vertical spacing of the labels in the legend to fit things in nicely (use the `labelspacing` kwarg).

And finally, I added a new line at the beginning of the legend labels to make it all look nice (`label='\nHatch 1'`).

A complete script is below. You may wish to play around with the values of `labelspacing`, `handlelength`, `patch.set_height()` and `patch.set_y()` to suit your needs.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

n = 5
hatch_1 = 'o'
hatch_2 = '.'
opacity = 0.4
bar_width = 0.4

y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=n)
x = np.arange(n)

bars = plt.bar(x, y, bar_width, align='center',  alpha=opacity, fill=False)
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_hatch(hatch_1)

y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=n)
bars = plt.bar(x + bar_width, y, bar_width,
               align='center',  alpha=opacity, fill=False)
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_hatch(hatch_2)

patch_1 = Patch(fill=False, label='\nHatch 1', hatch=hatch_1, alpha=opacity)
patch_2 = Patch(fill=False, label='\nHatch 2', hatch=hatch_2, alpha=opacity)

# add legends
leg = plt.legend(handles=[patch_1, patch_2], loc='upper right', labelspacing=1.5, handlelength=4)

for patch in leg.get_patches():
    patch.set_height(22)
    patch.set_y(-6)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. This is a cool workaround. It shows the power of customization which can be done in `matplotlib`. Thank you very much!

Comment: @tmdavison's workaround is really nice (and I'm using it). However, this does _not_ show the "power" of matplotlib customization but rather the lack of good defaults for hatch sizes in legends.

Comment: `handleheight` is now an argument to `plt.legend()` (as of 3.5 but maybe earlier versions). See also my answer below.

Comment: Nice, good to know @rileyx

Answer (score 2):

As of 3.5.0 (and maybe earlier), `handleheight` and `handlelength` are now options to [`plt.legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html). Using your code but replacing the call to `plt.legend()` with

```
plt.legend(handles=[patch_1, patch_2], loc='upper right', handleheight=3, handlelength=4)
```

gives the following:
[image]

Comment: A quick look at the repository suggests `handleheight` has been there as an option to `plt.legend` for a long time... but was only added to the documentation in v3.5.0 !

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 5
hatch_1 = 'O'
hatch_2 = '.'
opacity = 0.4
bar_width = 0.4

y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=n)
x = np.arange(n)

bars = plt.bar(x, y, bar_width, align='center',  alpha=opacity, fill=False)
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_hatch(hatch_1)

y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=n)
bars = plt.bar(x + bar_width, y, bar_width,
               align='center',  alpha=opacity, fill=False)
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_hatch(hatch_2)

patch_1 = Patch(fill=False, label='Hatch 1', hatch=hatch_1, alpha=opacity)
patch_2 = Patch(fill=False, label='Hatch 2', hatch=hatch_2, alpha=opacity)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (25,15)
# add legends
plt.legend(handles=[patch_1, patch_2], loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

Made your small o as O and increase the size of figure that will make sense i guess

Comment: The main issue here is the legend showing hatch. The size of the box is so small that it is difficult to understand in a quick look.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way offered by `matplotlib` in my opinion is to define the properties of the legend using `prop` size to increase/decrease the legend size. You just need to do the following where you can choose the `'size'` as preferred.

```
plt.legend(handles=[patch_1, patch_2], loc='best', prop={'size': 24})
```

[image]

Comment: `prop` is used to modify the font properties (in this case just the font size) in the legend. This will modify the patch size too, but it comes at the cost of changing the font size to be much larger than the font for the axis labels, etc.

Comment: @tmdavison: True that. Good catch

Comment: Thank you very much. As @tmdavison mentioned, the drawback of using `prop` is that the font size is getting much larger.

Answer (score 1):

While @tmdavison's solution works great, it is a bit involved.

Since the main issue here is that hatches are not easy to recognize in legends, a less ideal but much simpler workaround is to increase the hatch density, which is achieved simply by repeating the desired hatch character, ie, replacing `o` with `ooo`:

```py
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

n = 5
hatch_1 = 'o'
hatch_2 = 'ooo'
opacity = 0.4
bar_width = 0.4

y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=n)
x = np.arange(n)

bars = plt.bar(x, y, bar_width, align='center',  alpha=opacity, fill=False)
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_hatch(hatch_1)

y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=n)
bars = plt.bar(x + bar_width, y, bar_width,
               align='center',  alpha=opacity, fill=False)
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_hatch(hatch_2)

patch_1 = Patch(fill=False, label='Hatch 1', hatch=hatch_1, alpha=opacity)
patch_2 = Patch(fill=False, label='Hatch 2', hatch=hatch_2, alpha=opacity)

# add legends
plt.legend(handles=[patch_1, patch_2], loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot with different hatch densities]