# Matplotlib: display legend keys for lines as patches by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

For background, see the [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html).

I want to display legend keys for [`Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html) objects as [`Patches`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html) (with the same color and label), by default. What is the cleanest way to do this? I tried using [`update_default_handler_map`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend.update_default_handler_map) with a `handler_map` but keep getting errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can display legend as patches doing the following:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

colors = [['#01FF4F','#00FFff'],
           ['#FFEB00','#FFFF00']]
categories = ['A','B']
# categories and colors inside a dict
legend_dict=dict(zip(categories,colors))
# setting up lines for the plot and list for patches
patchList = []
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# assigning each inner color for each categories to their respective plot lines and legend/patches
for key in legend_dict:
        data_key = mpatches.Patch(facecolor=legend_dict[key][0],
                                  edgecolor=legend_dict[key][1], label=key)
        ax.plot(np.random.randn(100).cumsum(), color=legend_dict[key][0], label=legend_dict[key][1])
        patchList.append(data_key)

ax.legend(handles=patchList, ncol=len(categories), fontsize='small')
plt.show()
```

Which output:
[image]

I didn't know matplotlib before making this answer, so I had to mix two or three SO post to get this far (and trying/failing for a bit). Here they are, in a non-special order:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791790/12349101
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/73832036/12349101 (one line from answer of this post)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39500357/12349101

Since you mentioned Line2d:

```py
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

colors = [['#01FF4F','#00FFff'],
           ['#FFEB00','#FFFF00']]
categories = ['A','B']
# categories and colors inside a dict
legend_dict=dict(zip(categories,colors))
# setting up lines for the plot and list for patches
patchList = []
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# assigning each inner color for each categories to their respective plot lines and legend/patches
for key in legend_dict:
        data_key = mpatches.Patch(facecolor=legend_dict[key][0],
                                  edgecolor=legend_dict[key][1], label=key)
        ax.plot(Line2D(np.random.randn(100).cumsum(), np.random.randn(100).cumsum()).get_data(), color=legend_dict[key][0], label=legend_dict[key][1])
        patchList.append(data_key)

ax.legend(handles=patchList, ncol=len(categories), fontsize='small')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

One intriguing and related to patches as legend post that I can't help but link to: [Make patches bigger used as legend inside matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849888/make-patches-bigger-used-as-legend-inside-matplotlib)

lastly, here is a decent excerpt related to customizing legend on matplotlib: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.06-customizing-legends.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm looking for a way to do this automatically by default (hence the comment about update_default_handler_map), i.e. once in the entire program rather than once in each plotting routine.

Comment: I don't think I know enough about matplotlib (what I posted above are merely examples ). I did find however something you could do that would help you do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57697692/12349101 By using a class, you could then pass that to the `update_default_handler_map` and it would work as it is. @user76284

Answer (score 0):

Making this appear by default probably wouldn't work, as there are too many differences between lines and patches. Lines can have a line width, markes, line styles, ... . Patches can have an outline, hatching, ....

For a simple situation with just a colored, you might use rectangles:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.random.randn(100).cumsum(), color='tomato', label='red line')
ax.plot(np.random.randn(100).cumsum(), color='cornflowerblue', alpha=0.6, label='blue line')

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
new_handles = [h if type(h) != matplotlib.lines.Line2D
               else plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, lw=0, color=h.get_color(), alpha=h.get_alpha()) for h in handles]

ax.legend(new_handles, labels)
plt.show()
```

[image: showing lines as patches in legend]

Comment: "there are too many differences between lines and patches" I just want the patches to have the same color (and label).

Comment: I would like to make it a default setting, as stated in the question. In particular, I want to avoid doing this manually for every plot. (Aside: Why rectangle rather than patch, which likewise has a color parameter?)

Comment: I meant falling into the trap of these functions gets you into similar troubles as editing the source code. It really is a bad idea.